# How to show/hide a reply text box using Flask and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

I haven't used HTML/Javascript in a while so I am a bit confused on how to handle this.

I am building a reddit-y clone using Flask.  I am at the point where I can add children comments to any comment and have things display nicely, but when I was testing with that I just had the reply text box/submit button always visible for every comment, I want to try to emulate the actual reddit behavior where there is some text that says "reply" and on clicking it a text box appears.

Here is my current HTML, which shows a textbox/submit button for every comment.  How can I use jQuery (or even vanilla JS)to make it such that only upon clicking some other text that says `reply` will it show?

```
<ul>
  {%- for comment in comments recursive %}
    <li>
        {{ comment.commentContent }}

        <form action="{{ url_for('blog.addComment', postId=post['id'], redirectHere=True, parentComment=comment['id'])}}" method="post">
            <textarea name="comment"></textarea>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>

        {%- if comment.children_comments -%}
            <ul>{{ loop(comment.children_comments) }}</ul>
        {%- endif %}
    </li>
  {%- endfor %}
</ul>
```

I was caught between two minds.  Should I have a div for each comment initially set to invisible, and upon clicking `reply` it would make the text area/form visible?  Or would it be better to wait for someone to click `reply` and then dynamically using jQuery append the form in the HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best bet is to use boostraps collapse option for hiding and showing comment text box.  The code belows shows you how it works

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Hide and show comment box</button>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
comment box appears here
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now to apply it to your code for showing and hiding comment box, 
I need to use your **comment id** so as to make each button comment click unique.
if you gets your comment id as `{{ comment.commentid }}` then pass it to **demo id** and **data-target** parameters

so with **bootsraps and jquery** file your code will look like

```
    <ul>
      {%- for comment in comments recursive %}
        <li>
            {{ comment.commentContent }}

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo{{ comment.commentid }}">Hide and show comment box</button>
       <div id="demo{{ comment.commentid }}" class="collapse">

            <form action="{{ url_for('blog.addComment', postId=post['id'], redirectHere=True, parentComment=comment['id'])}}" method="post">
                <textarea name="comment"></textarea>
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
    </div>

        {%- if comment.children_comments -%}
            <ul>{{ loop(comment.children_comments) }}</ul>
        {%- endif %}
    </li>
  {%- endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: I will try this later, thank you.  If it works the solution is yours.

Comment: It will but also remember to upvote as well. just stick to the concept

Comment: Am glad it works. You can now accept it as answer. also remember to also upvote. thanks